# Can I generate heat map using method such as Grad-CAM in concatenated CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network, visualization

I am trying to apply GradCAM to my pre-trained CNN model to generate heat maps of layers. My custom CNN design is shown as follows:
- It adopted all the convolution layers and the pre-trained weights from the VGG16 model.
- Extract lower level features (early convolution layers) from VGG16. 
- Train the fully connected layers of both normal/high and lower level features from VGG16.
- Concatenate outputs of both normal/high- and lower-level f.c. layers and then train more f.c. layers before the final prediction.

[model design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG58f.png)

I want to use GradCAM to visualize the feature maps of the low-level route and the normal/high-level route and I have done such heatmaps on non-concatenate fine-tuned VGG using the last convolutional layers. My question is, on a concatenated CNN model, can the Grad-CAM method still work using the gradient of the prediction with respect to the low- and high-level feature map feature maps respectfully? If not, are there other methods that can do the heatmaps visualization for such a model? Is using the shared fully connected layer an option?

Any idea and suggestions are much appreciated!